# Python - must we have an __init__.py in every step of a directory in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, import, directory, environment-variables

Lets say that we want **on Windows** with `Python 2.7` to either run a command **from the GUI** by typing it and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> or **right-click on the Python file and choose Edit with IDLE** and when IDLE pops up inside IDLE press <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Now assume that we have a simplistic file directory like `C:\A\B\C\D` and inside `folder D` we want to run the `example.py`. We want to do it by a certain way which is either:

- By opening it with a right-click and choose edit with IDLE and pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> or
- By picking up every line of code and typing her on the Python GUI

Let us say that we type the command:

```
from C.D import example
```

Please bear in mind that `C and D are folders` and inside `folder D` we have `example.py`. We also set up the environment variable: `C:\A\B\C;` in PYTHONPATH so that `Python` can see `folder D` as a module and inside of it operate with the `example.py` submodule.

**Is it necessary** to have an `__init__.py` in **every folder before the File D?**

**If** `file A` or `file B` do **NOT** have an `__init__.py` can `Python` (remember we have typed in the environment variable) go to `file C`?

Is it a must that in every step of the way *aka* in every folder in the directory to have an `__init__.py`?

Comment: Python's package behaviour doesn't vary between operating systems; it doesn't matter if this is Windows.

Comment: I was stressing that we are on Windows because of the way that i test code lines in the particular OS which is by either picking each line and typing her on the GUI or by pressing F5 inside the IDLE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to add `__init__.py` to directories that must be treated as packages. Any folder outside the `PYTHONPATH` search path is *never* a package and doesn't need to have an `__init__.py`.

You don't need `__init__` in the top-level directory listed on `PYTHONPATH` either, because that's not a package. `C` is not a package here, it is a folder on module search path. You cannot import from `C`; only `D` is a package.

For your setup, if `C:A\B\C` is on the module search path, then only items *in* `C` can be imported. `C:A\B\C\module.py` is importable as `module`, and `C:A\B\C\D\` is importable if there is an `__init__.py` file in that directory, as `import D`.

Python uses the search path to find top-level names you import; if you try to import `foo`, the search path is tried one by one, each a location on your harddisk. `C:\A\B\C` is one such location, it'll look *inside* that location, but the directory name of the location is never part of the search space.

See the [Python tutorial on packages](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) for more information.

Comment: Why i cannot import C if it has an `__init__.py`?

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant: because it is not *in* the python path; you'd need to add `C:\A\B` to the path, not `C:\A\B\C`.

Comment: How do we actually now that a folder is outside the PYTHONPATH search path? I mean that a directory is like a chain in order python to go to folder C it must pass from B they coexist. Dont they?

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant: When you import `C`, Python looks for `C:\A\B\C\C`, as that's one of the places to look for top-level modules and packages.

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant: Python doesn't view the search path directories as a chain. It's just a location on the harddisk.

Comment: Please correct me if i am wrong but i had a very strong impression that if i want to import `C` i must set up an environment variable which is `C:\A\B;` in order that Python goes there and treats C as a module. Is that correct or not?